# How do I properly scale the covariance matrix in a weighted Gaussian mixture model for new samples?

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, weights

I am trying to implement the method for computing a Gaussian mixture model from samples with known weights as detailed in section III of:

**EM Algorithms for Weighted-Data Clustering
with Application to Audio-Visual Scene Analysis** by Gebru et al.

which is available here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.01509

To summarize, they state that the uncertainty of a given point $\bf{x}_i$ with a weight $w_i$ for the $k$th component of the mixture model with mean $\bf{\mu}_k$ and covariance matrix $\bf{\Sigma}_k$ can be defined as:

$\hat{p}\left(\bf{x}_i, \bf{\mu}_k, \bf{\Sigma}_k, w_i\right) = \mathcal{N}\left(\bf{x}_i, \bf{\mu}_k,  \frac{1}{w_i} \bf{\Sigma}_k\right)$

This leads to the mixture model formulation:

$\tilde{p}\left(\bf{x}_i, \bf{\Theta}, w_i\right) = \sum_{k=1}^K \pi_k \hat{p}\left(\bf{x}_i, \bf{\mu}_k, \bf{\Sigma}_k, w_i\right)$.

where $\pi_k$ is the weight of the $k$th mixture component and I've added subscripts to $\bf{x}_i$ and $\bf{w}_i$ because I think that is consistent with what they are trying to do.

They then describe a Expectation Maximization routine to determine the parameters of the mixture model via the computation of the posteriors on the data for each of the mixture components:

$\eta_{ik}^{r+1} = \frac{\pi_{k}^k \hat{p}\left(\bf{x}_i, \bf{\mu}_k, \bf{\Sigma}_k, w_i\right)}{\tilde{p}\left(\bf{x}_i, \bf{\Theta}, w_i\right)}$

from there, they update the component weights with

$\pi_k^{r+1} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \eta_{ik}^{r+1} \pi_k$

followed by the means

$\bf{\mu}_k^{r+1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i \eta_{ik}^{r+1} \bf{x}_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i \eta_{ik}^{r+1}}$

and then followed by the covariance matrices

$ \bf{\Sigma}_{k}^{r+1} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i \eta_{ik}^{r+1} \left(\bf{x}_i - \mu_k^{r+1}\right)\left(\bf{x}_i - \bf{\mu}_k^{r+1}\right)^T}{\sum_{i=1}^n \eta_{ik}^{r+1}}$.

I've implemented this into code and am getting results that are comparible to a known mixture of Gaussians for the $\pi_k$s and the $\mu_k$s. The relative ratio of the components of the covariance seems to be correct but the scaling of those terms is smaller than what I expect. I attribute this to the $\frac{1}{w}$ factor in the mixture model formulation.

I now want to evaluate the log pdf of the mixture model for some new point $\bf{x}_j$ at which I don't know the weight $w_j$. Because my covariance matrices are scaled by $w$ I get log pdf values much smaller than what I expect.

I found that by dividing my covariance matrices by the mean of the weights of my training points I was able to get a log pdf result that is more in line with what I expect. My problem is knowing if this is generally true and/or justifying it.

What is the proper way to scale my covariance matrices returned by the weighted Gaussian mixture model on new points?